# How to remove the transparent field around the plank dock?

Tags: dock, plank

I have installed plank and noticed the transparent field with a distinct border (which is not only visible, windows even stick to it when dragged near) around it. Below a picture where I have highlighted a part of it. How to get rid of this effect? I have seen many screen shots of plank without this but switching themes in the settings doesn't seem to help. Nor could I find the option to disable it.

[image: Plank border example]

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if you've figured this out, but in:

> Settings Manager > Window Manager Tweaks > Compositor

uncheck "Show shadows under dock windows".

If you use picom, then edit ~/.config/picom/picom.conf and add `"class_g = 'plank'"` to the `shadow_exclude` list.